# Error Handling in T-SQL Scalar Function

Tags: sql-server-2005, function, error-handling, sql-server-2000, type-conversion

This question could easily take multiple paths, so I will hit the more specific path first. While working with SQL Server 2005, I'm trying to create a scalar function that acts as a 'TryCast' from varchar to int.  Where I encounter a problem is when I add a TRY block in the function;

```
CREATE FUNCTION u_TryCastInt
(
   @Value as VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS Int
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Output AS Int

   BEGIN TRY
      SET @Output = CONVERT(Int, @Value)
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
      SET @Output = 0
   END CATCH

   RETURN @Output
END
```

Turns out theres all sorts of things wrong with this statement including "Invalid use of side-effecting or time-dependent operator in 'BEGIN TRY' within a function" and "Invalid use of side-effecting or time-dependent operator in 'END TRY' within a function".  I can't seem to find any examples of using try statements within a scalar function, which got me thinking, is error handling in a function is possible?

The goal here is to make a robust version of the Convert or Cast functions to allow a SELECT statement carry through depsite conversion errors. For example, take the following;

```
    CREATE TABLE tblTest
    (
        f1 VARCHAR(50)
    )
    GO

    INSERT INTO tblTest(f1) VALUES('1')
    INSERT INTO tblTest(f1) VALUES('2')
    INSERT INTO tblTest(f1) VALUES('3')
    INSERT INTO tblTest(f1) VALUES('f')
    INSERT INTO tblTest(f1) VALUES('5')
    INSERT INTO tblTest(f1) VALUES('1.1')

    SELECT CONVERT(int,f1) AS f1_num FROM tblTest

    DROP TABLE tblTest
```

It never reaches point of dropping the table because the execution gets hung on trying to convert 'f' to an integer.  I want to be able to do something like this;

```
SELECT u_TryCastInt(f1) AS f1_num FROM tblTest

fi_num
__________
1
2
3
0
5
0
```

Any thoughts on this?  Is there anything that exists that handles this?  Also, I would like to try and expand the conversation to support SQL Server 2000 since Try blocks are not an option in that scenario.

Comment: For your particular use case this might help. http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6423

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if you can convert to int first, check out the IsInteger function here: [IsNumeric, IsInt, IsNumber](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/isnumeric-isint-isnumber)  It will work on 2000 and up

Answer (score 2):

And, to answer in general: No, you can't use try-catch logic in a function. I can sort of see why - or at least it's clearly preferable to avoid it, given the huge performance penalty that would come with it.

However, I think it is odd that one also cannot RAISE an error in a function... that's something built-in functions already do. I suppose one has to get by returning NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The TRY…CATCH construct cannot be used in a user-defined function in SQL 2012!

See this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

When I try to use this script:

```
CREATE FUNCTION u_TryCastInt
(
   @Value as VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS Int
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Output AS Int

   BEGIN TRY
      SET @Output = CONVERT(Int, @Value)
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
      SET @Output = 0
   END CATCH

   RETURN @Output
END
```

I got error:

> Msg 443, Level 16, State 14, Procedure u_TryCastInt, Line 10
>   Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'BEGIN TRY' within a function.
>   Msg 443, Level 16, State 14, Procedure u_TryCastInt, Line 12
>   Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'END TRY' within a function.
>   Msg 443, Level 16, State 14, Procedure u_TryCastInt, Line 13
>   Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'BEGIN CATCH' within a function.
>   Msg 443, Level 16, State 14, Procedure u_TryCastInt, Line 15
>   Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'END CATCH' within a function.